# How can I use SQL MERGE to insert if not exists, and SET a variable to the Id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-merge

I have an Id column set by `SEQUENCE` 
Given a `varchar` I need to `INSERT` if there is not match, and return an Id.

The Id will be either:

- The existing Id of the row with the matchine ItemName
- The new Id generated by the sequence because a row was inserted
- `NULL` because the string was passed as `NULL`

I'm trying to `MERGE` into the table to insert if not exists, otherwise get the Id. I need it to be threadsafe.

Here is what I have so far but I'm thinking there is a better way:

```
DECLARE @vValueId INT NULL
DECLARE @inserted AS TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL)

MERGE 
    dbo.foo WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS f 
USING 
    (SELECT @vName AS val WHERE @vName IS NOT NULL) AS new_item
        ON f.ItemName = new_item.val
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @vValueId = f.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT
      (ItemName)
    VALUES
      (@vName)
OUTPUT inserted.Id AS Id INTO @inserted;

SELECT @vValueId = ISNULL(s.Id, @vValueId) FROM @inserted AS s
```

Comment: I don't really understand the need of using meagre in this situation. If there is a match you don't update the table, so why not just use a simple insert instead?

Comment: @ZoharPeled because this is a threadsafe insert and retrieves the values without a second query. How would you do it instead? Remember that I need the Id value.